# When to use float and when to use double?

Tags: java

I've read through some of the questions here about floats vs doubles which were very helpful with explaining the difference. 
Can someone help with explaining why you would use a float instead of a double if the double is more precise?
Does it have to do with memory and performance (32bits vs 64bits)?

Comment: Use search function, there are many posts about this.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I'm not sure why that question didn't show in the results for any of my searches, but I'm glad to have the information.

Comment: Visit http://net-informations.com/q/faq/float.html

Comment: A double needs 8 bytes of storage space while a float needs just 4 bytes, so range(and precision also) of number for a double is larger.